# Add custom button to navigation controller without border

Tags: xcode, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I add custom button to navigation controller

```
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(backAction)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

it works fine, but button appears bordered. How can I fix that?

**UPDATE**
I found solution

```
   
 UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonFavoriteClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    [button release];
```

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this.

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, button_width, button_height)];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 4

```
let backButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "back.png"), for: .normal)
backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backAction), for: .touchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
```

And action (selector) should be like the following :

```
@objc func backAction () {
        // do the magic 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Adding Button either in left or right with title or without title as per the requirement,

```
func addBarButton(image: UIImage?, isLeft: Bool = true, title: String? = nil, font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16), tintColor: UIColor = R.color.textfieldColor() ?? .black) {
            if let navController = self.navigationController {
                let navBar = navController.navigationBar
                navBar.isHidden = false
                navBar.isTranslucent = false
                let btn = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
                if let img = image {
                    btn.setImage(img, for: UIControl.State.normal)
                }
                if let titleTxt = title {
                    btn.setTitle(titleTxt, for: .normal)
                    btn.setTitleColor(tintColor, for: .normal)
                    btn.titleLabel?.font = font
                }
                btn.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
                btn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
                let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: btn)
                if isLeft {
                    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnLeftNavigationClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
                    btn.tintColor = tintColor
                    if let tabBar = self.tabBarController {
                        tabBar.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
                        tabBar.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
                    } else {
                        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
                        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
                    }

                } else {
                    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnRightNavigationClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
                    btn.tintColor = tintColor
                    if let tabBar = self.tabBarController {
                        tabBar.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
                    } else {
                        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

> Right button action

```
@objc func btnRightNavigationClicked(sender: UIButton) { 
   // add your logic here         
}
```

> Left button action

```
@objc func btnLeftNavigationClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        guard let navigationController = self.navigationController else {
            return
        }
        navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```